# Well-ordering of natural numbers from axioms of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $(\mathbb R,+,\times,<)$ be an ordered field that is Dedekind complete. Let $\mathbb N$ be the intersection of all additive submonoids $M \subseteq \mathbb R$ with $1 \in M$. The question is, can we prove that every subset of $\mathbb N$ has a least element (i.e. well-ordering principle)? If not, can we "construct" a model of $\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb N$ does not have the well-ordering principle (apologize for the language as I am not a model theorist)?

This is inspired by the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2214227/553409, although I don't think Proposition 3 in the cited answer works. In particular, elements of $\mathbb N$ may get arbitrarily closed to each other.
[1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2214227/553409

Comment: Yes, and it's not necessary to assume Dedekind completeness, this is true for any ordered field. Just show that $\mathbb{N}$ is the additive submonoid generated by $1$ and that this monoid is isomorphic to the usual $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan isn't the point to not "know" what the usual $\mathbb{N}$ and its properties are?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that the usual naturals exist and are a monoid, than per Qiaochu Yuan's comment it's kind of immediate.

However, you can prove it without this fact.  That is, without the axiom of infinity, (and, for that matter, without using completeness of the reals, which is unnecessary and generally not helpful*), just starting from the fact (taken as axiom) that $\mathbb R$ is an ordered integral domain, you can argue that the smallest inductive subset (i.e., a subset $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ such that $1\in S$ and such that $x\in S$ implies $x+1\in S$) [is well-ordered.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4776665/1210477)

From that, you can show (essentially by the same induction-type arguments used in the link, or you can use actual induction since you have established well-ordering) that such a minimal inductive set is a submonoid, and therefore the minimal submonoid containing $1$ is contained in the minimal inductive set.  But a submonoid containing $1$ is itself inductive, so the minimal such submonoid then coincides with the minimal inductive set, and is therefore well-ordered as well.

##### update

I missed the fact that since we are talking about additive monoids, we should slightly alter the definition of inductive set to say that $S$ is inductive if $0\in S$ and whenever $x\in S$, $x+1\in S$.  All of the arguments (including at the link) still go exactly the same way.

*(I also do not understand proposition 3 at the link you provided, it seems unjustified to me.)

Answer (score 0):

$1\in M \implies \mathbb N \subseteq M$

$\forall M, 1\in M\implies \forall M, \mathbb N\subseteq M$

$\mathbb N \cap M = \mathbb N.$

Let $E\subseteq  \mathbb N, E \ne \emptyset$.

$x\in E \implies x>0$.

So E is non-empty and bounded below.

Every non-empty subset of the reals that is bounded below has a greatest lower bound as a corollary of the Completeness Axiom of the Reals.

So $\exists \alpha\in \mathbb R, x\in E \implies \alpha \le x.$

$ \exists x\in E | \alpha \le x\le \alpha+1 $ otherwise $\alpha +1$ itself would be a lower bound of E contradicting the assumption that $\alpha$ is the g.l.b.

Suppose $\alpha< x \le \alpha +1, y\in E$.

$\alpha \le x \le \alpha +1 \le x+1$ and suppose $x<y<x+1$

Then $\alpha -x \le 0 \le \alpha +1-x\le 1$ and $0<y-x<1$. This implies $x$ and $y$ are elements of a non-minimal sub-monoid.

So $x$ is a greater lower bound. Again contradicting the assumption that $\alpha$ is the greatest lower bound.

So $x=\alpha \in E$.

So every non-empty subset of the natural numbers  contains a least element: This is the well-ordering principle.

Comment: I'm not quite following this update. You supposed $y\in E$ with $x<y<x+1$, then concluded $y-x\in (0,1)$, but how does that imply anything about $y$ and $x$ individually?